# Swift: updating Apple maps instead of Launching it everytime

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

How are you?

i am trying to Launch and update Apple maps with the command line Latitude and longitude. 
i am using the following code:

```
func openMapForPlace() 
{
  var lat1 : NSString = self.venueLat
  var lng1 : NSString = self.venueLng
  var latitute:CLLocationDegrees =  lat1.doubleValue
  var longitute:CLLocationDegrees =  lng1.doubleValue
  let regionDistance:CLLocationDistance = 10000
  var coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitute, longitute)
  let regionSpan = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinates, regionDistance, regionDistance)
  var options = [
  MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: NSValue(MKCoordinate: regionSpan.center),
  MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey: NSValue(MKCoordinateSpan: regionSpan.span)
                ]
  var placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates, addressDictionary: nil)
  var mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
  mapItem.name = "\(self.venueName)"
  mapItem.openInMapsWithLaunchOptions(options)
}
```

the problem here is, when i am trying to call this function infinite loop.
Because this function launching apple maps every time, i couldn't do other task.
Apple maps keep popping-up front continuously.

please help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: why you call `when i am trying to call this function infinite loop` this

Comment: Sorry. i did not get you. 
Consider there is a periodic session running background. which can get the latitude and longitude for every 1 sec and it will use this function to show the fix details on map. That is why i said "calling this function infinite loop". I want to update the apple map with fix details instead of using openInMapsWithLaunchOptions method.

Comment: i want to modify placemark on the mapitem.

Answer (score -1):

Finally i figured out what i am missing.

To access the properties of the Map i have to use a MapView class instead of MapItem class.

This MapView is for integrating maps to your cocoa and cocoa touch applications.
We can use animations, annotations, directions for the MapView class.

MapView - [MapView Class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/index.html)

mapKit - [MapItem Class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapItem_class/index.html)